# Randomized image height not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm trying to type a JavaScript function where, when the user types a given key on the keyboard, the corresponding image with a random height attribute between 33px and 47px is added to the output div.

In the CSS I have this:

```
img {
  margin: 0 1px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

Here's what I have in the JS script:

```
var outputStuff = "<br />";
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
if (event.keyCode == 65) {
var arrayA = [ //several images of the letter 'a' to randomly choose from
              ];
             var longy = arrayA.length;
             var randy = Math.floor((Math.random())*longy);
             outputStuff = outputStuff + arrayA[randy];
             document.getElementById('showType').innerHTML = outputStuff;
}
// a lot of 'else if' code here for B-Z, 0-9, etc. all of this works fine

var sloppy = (40 + Math.round(14 * (Math.random() - 0.5))) + "px";
    document.getElementsByTageName("img").style.height=sloppy; // this is line 517
```

No matter what I do, my Javascript Console always gives me "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" at line 517, and the height for every image stays at 40px. Can anyone tell me where the issue is?

Comment: you have syntax error, `getElementsByTageName` is wrong. compiler tells you where to look.

Answer (score 0):

On the last line, it's supposed to spell `getElementsByTagName`, not `getElementsByTageName`.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("img").style.height=sloppy; // should work
```